# Grails - Updating a TD located within a template

Tags: grails

I have a table that has columns in a template:

```
<div id="petDiv">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <g:sortableColumn property="breed" title="${message(code: 'contact.breed.label', default: 'Breed')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="age" title="${message(code: 'contact.age.label', default: 'Age')}" />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <g:each in="${availablePets}" status="i" var="pet">
                            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                            <td><g:link action="show" id="${pet.id}">${fieldValue(bean: pet, field: "Breed")}</g:link></td>
                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: pet, field: "Age")}</g:link></td>
                            <td>
                                <g:form>
                                    <fieldset class="pDivB">
                                        <g:remoteLink action="updatePet" update="another template here??" params: [] >Update</g:remoteLink>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </g:form>
                            </td>   
                            </tr>
                    </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

I want:

```
Hit link
Go to updatePet method in Controller with the ID of that pet
Update my <td> tags for breed and age for that row only
```

I tried using a jQuery/Javascript combination I read online, but it updates the first row only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some sample code that does something similar - https://github.com/aldrinm/grails-sample-code

Hope that helps.